# How to make just some of the points selectable in CorePlot?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I'm using *CorePlot* in my project. I have a scatterPlot graph with large amount of data points. **Some** of my points (**but not all**) need to be able to respond to user hits. How can I achieve this?

I have set `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` to 15.0f, but it applies to all the points, not to the some of them that I need to be selectable. Is it possible to set variable `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` values for different points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Either ignore hits on points that you don't want or split the plot into two separate plots—one that responds to user interaction and one that doesn't.

Comment: Hello Eric, I have hoped you would respond. First of all thanks a lot! Unfortunately ignoring hits doesn't help much - I still have about 300 points with interlapping hit-area and I can't make just few of the dots (5-10) to be hittable so. But the idea of two separate plots sounds good, I think that would be the solution. Thanks!